# Finding a differential equation, given two solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a differential equation that satisfies the solutions $$y_1 (x) = x $$ and $$ y_2 (x) = \ln(x)$$ on the interval $( 0, + \infty)$. Since these two solutions are linearly independent, I know that the differential equation will have to be of second order. But I cannot come up with one. Is there some general method to come up with differential equations, given some solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general solution (if you want a linear differential equation) is

$$y=c_1x + c_2 \ln{x}$$
then 
$$y'=c_1+\frac{c_2}{x}$$
and
$$y''=\frac{-c_2}{x^2}$$
One way to come up with a differential equation is to use these three equations and eliminate the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.
From the last equation you know that $c_2=-x^2y''$.  Putting this in the second equation yields
$$y'=c_1-xy''$$
or 
$$c_1=y'+xy''$$
which you can insert into the first equation for $c_1$
to yield
$$y= (y'+xy'')x-x^2y''\ln{x}$$

Comment: Thank you! That was very clear and helpful.

Comment: More generally, $$\left|\begin{array}{cc}y''_1&y''_2\\ y'_1&y'_2\end{array}\right|\cdot y=\left|\begin{array}{cc}y''&y''_2\\ y'&y'_2\end{array}\right|\cdot y_1+\left|\begin{array}{cc}y''_1&y''\\ y'_1&y'\end{array}\right|\cdot y_2,$$ which is equivalent to $$\left|\begin{array}{cc}y''_1&y''_2\\ y'_1&y'_2\end{array}\right|\cdot y=\left|\begin{array}{cc}y_1&y_2\\ y'_1&y'_2\end{array}\right|\cdot y''+\left|\begin{array}{cc}y''_1&y''_2\\ y_1&y_2\end{array}\right|\cdot y'.$$